# automount bindfs upon boot up

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, mount

How to execute this command upon boot up.

```
sudo bindfs -o perms=0755,mirror-only=www-data,force-group=www-data,force-user=www-data /home/vagrant/www /var/www
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the command in my /etc/rc.local file and it works fine.